# javascript extending Array class

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code? I'm trying to extend the class foo with all the native array's functions.

```
function foo(){
    Array.call(this);
 }

foo.prototype.addFruit=function(item){
    this.unshift(item);
}
foo.prototype=new Array();
foo.prototype.constructor=foo;

var c =new foo();

c.addFruit('Apple');


document.write(c.join('-'));
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the method `addFruit` to the `prototype` of `foo`, then you overwrote the the `foo.prototype`, so the method is missing (**The prototype changed to another object after you put a method to the original prototype**).

You should change your order of the code, assign the `prototype` before add method to `prototype`.

```
foo.prototype=new Array();
foo.prototype.constructor=foo;

foo.prototype.addFruit=function(item){
    this.unshift(item);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You add the `addFruit` property to the prototype before you overwrite the whole `prototype` property with a `new Array`.

Instead of `new Array`, you should use `Object.create(Array.prototype)` so you don't have an actual Array *instance* as the prototype (with `length` etc) but only an object inheriting from the Array prototype.

`Array.call(this)` unfortunately does not work. It returns a new array, which is assigned to nothing, but it does not do anything on `this`. You can check by `this !== Array.call(this)`. Actually, it is not possible to "subclass" `Array` - read on http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array

Comment: thanks but what is the difference between foo.prototype=Object.create(Array.prototype);
and
foo.prototype=Array.prototype;

Comment: The second one assigns one to the other, so that `foo.prototype === Array.prototype`, while [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object with a properly set-up prototype chain.